# Efeito de transição de entrada jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá, eu queria que quando abrisse uma página minha imagem viesse de baixo pra cima, e quando chegasse no topo ela desaparecesse, tudo isso em 10 segundos.
Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada em `Effects` do jQuery? https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Deu uma olhada sim, mas eu sou iniciante nessas linguagens, e acho que eu não saberia montar o código. Mas obrigado por ter me passado o site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções [ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), [slideUp()](https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), [slideDown()](https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) e [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) pra atingir o que quer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".subir").slideDown().animate({
        bottom: $(document).height()
    }, 10000);
});
```

No código, a função que está sendo passada pra `ready()` do `document` só vai ser chamado quando todos os elementos da página forem carregados. Depois usa-se `slideDown()` e `animate()` pra mover a div que contem a imagem de baixo pro topo, por isso passamos `$(document).height()` como opção `bottom` do efeito que vai durar por 10000ms(10s).

Aqui o DEMO no Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwza5y1r/1/

**OBS:** *Clique em 'Run' novamente se não ver o efeito, porque acontece quando a página carrega.*

**DEMO no Fiddle atualizado, mude os valores enviados pra slideDown() e animate() pra mudar a duração:** http://jsfiddle.net/andersonmadeira/b5pfptby/

Answer (score 1):

O código abaixo rodou certinho na minha maquina, só que aqui no SOPT e no jsfiddle não rodou o efeito, então faz um teste localhost que vai dar certo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
    
    <style type="text/css">         
        #imagem { 
            /*display: none;
            bottom: 0;
            position: absolute*/
        }
        .embaixo{ bottom: 0; position: absolute }
    </style>
</head>
<body>    
     <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a onclick="efeito()" href="#">Me clique</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="imagem" class="embaixo">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0CWZ.png" />
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function efeito(){        
        $("#imagem").animate({ top: 0 }, 2000,function(){ $(this).hide(); });         
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**Obs:** onde esta escrito 2000, mude para 10000 para aguardar os 10 segundos